Handling Incorrect Password or Username in Passport-ActiveDirectory Validate Function
I am creating a REST API using Nestjs and as part of authentication i needed to authenticate a user against my company active directory, I was able to use `passport-activedirectory' strategy to authenticate user and it is working fine.
The issue I am facing now is that when user enters either wrong password of username the validate function that handles the authentication in the backend just return a 401 Unauthorized response which is expected but i need to be able to provide a friendly message to the frontend that either the username or password is incorrect.
This is my active-directory.strtegy.ts file
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as Strategy from 'passport-activedirectory';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class ActiveDirectoryStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  'activedirectory',
) {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      integrated: false,
      ldap: {
        url: configService.get<string>('LDAPURL'),
        baseDN: configService.get<string>('LDAPBASEDN'),
        username: configService.get<string>('LDAPUSERNAME'),
        password: configService.get<string>('LDAPPASSWORD'),
      },
      clientOptions: {
        reconnect: true,
      },
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload.displayName;
  }
}

I tried wrapping my implementation inside the validate function in a trycatch but still did not work
 async validate(payload: any) {
    try {
      if (!payload) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
      }
      return payload.displayName;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Authentication failed:', error);
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
    }
  }

I've also tried to create an Unathourzed exception filter to catch the exception thrown in the validate function but doesn't seem to work
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Catch(UnauthorizedException)
export class UnauthorizedExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: UnauthorizedException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();
    const message = exception.message || 'Unauthorized';

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      message: message,
    });
  }
}

This is my auth.controller.ts
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class SignInResponseData {
  @ApiProperty()
  access_token: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  displayName: string;
}

import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
  Body,
  HttpCode,
  HttpStatus,
  Req,
  Get,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { SignInDto } from './dto/sign-in.dto';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { ApiOkResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './jwt-auth.guard';
import { ActiveDirectoryAuthGuard } from './active-directory-auth.guard';

@Controller('api/auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(ActiveDirectoryAuthGuard)
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ApiOkResponse({ type: SignInResponseData })
  @Post('sign-in')
  async signIn(@Body() signInDto: SignInDto, @Req() req: Request) {
    console.log(signInDto, req.user);
    return req.user;
  }
}

When user enters the coorect username and password, i get output to the log and a response of the user but when the username or password is invalid i just get an unathourized response.
How can I refactor the validate function to show a custom error when username or password is invalid
